# Select rows conditionally to estimate survival between years

Tags: r

I would like to select IDs that were captured in 2010 and that are recaptured in a later year. The problem here is that I know that some IDs that are not recaptured in 2010 were alive in the population because they were captured, for example, in 2009, not in 2010, and seen again in 2011. I want to select these IDs as well.

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(BANDFINAL = structure(c(6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("JP020", "JP1049", "JP1386", "JP1395/P789", 
"JP4762", "SH488_L", "SH714_L", "SH735_L", "SH760_L", "SH765_L"
), class = "factor"), ch = c("000000101010", "000000100000", 
"000000000010", "000000010000", "000000011000", "011111110100", 
"011101010000", "010110011000", "000000010101", "000000010000"
), y.2003 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), y.2004 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), y.2005 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0), y.2006 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), y.2007 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), y.2008 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0), y.2009 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), y.2010 = c(0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y.2011 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0), y.2012 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), y.2013 = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), y.2014 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0)), .Names = c("BANDFINAL", "ch", "y.2003", "y.2004", "y.2005", 
"y.2006", "y.2007", "y.2008", "y.2009", "y.2010", "y.2011", "y.2012", 
"y.2013", "y.2014"), row.names = c(2422L, 2521L, 1306L, 27L, 
2543L, 192L, 105L, 184L, 2533L, 2548L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the result.

```
      BANDFINAL           ch y.2003 y.2004 y.2005 y.2006 y.2007 y.2008 y.2009 y.2010 y.2011 y.2012 y.2013 y.2014
2422     SH488_L 000000101010      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
2521     SH714_L 000000100000      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
1306      JP4762 000000000010      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
27         JP020 000000010000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
2543     SH760_L 000000011000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
192  JP1395/P789 011111110100      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      0      0
105       JP1049 011101010000      0      1      1      1      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0
184       JP1386 010110011000      0      1      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
2533     SH735_L 000000010101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1
2548     SH765_L 000000010000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
```

As you can see here, ch is the capture history, and the rest of the columns are the same capture history, but split to see the year in the heading. The final result should look like this:

```
       BANDFINAL           ch y.2003 y.2004 y.2005 y.2006 y.2007 y.2008 y.2009 y.2010 y.2011 y.2012 y.2013 y.2014
2422     SH488_L 000000101010      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
2543     SH760_L 000000011000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
192  JP1395/P789 011111110100      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      0      0
184       JP1386 010110011000      0      1      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
2533     SH735_L 000000010101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1
```

As you can see, the first ID here of this last dataset was captured in 2009, not in 2010, and in 2011.

Do you know a way to execute this command?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you really mean to ask for cases that were known to be at risk of capture in 2010? As the question reads at the moment it appears that the first row in your proposed as answers does not  meet the criterion of being capture in 2010.

Comment: I understand, but to estimate survival _from_  2010, I need to know which ID was alive in 2010. Otherwise, I would eliminate that ID and loose a precious information about the survival of that bird from and after 2010. In that particular case, if I remove the ID that was not captured in 2010, but I know exists in 2009, I would not look for that bird.

Comment: Exactly. I had no quarrel with the strategy, only with your description of it. I thought it should be a request for "all birds captured prior to or during 2010".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially then what you need is for at least one `1` to exist on or before `2010` and at least another `1` to exist after 2010.

This code does exactly this:

```
df[ grepl('1', substr(df$ch,1,8)) & grepl('1', substr(df$ch,9,12)), ]
```

Output is the same as you need:

```
       BANDFINAL           ch y.2003 y.2004 y.2005 y.2006 y.2007 y.2008 y.2009 y.2010 y.2011 y.2012 y.2013 y.2014
2422     SH488_L 000000101010      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
2543     SH760_L 000000011000      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
192  JP1395/P789 011111110100      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      0      0
184       JP1386 010110011000      0      1      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
2533     SH735_L 000000010101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      1
```

Comment: Exactly, I have a much bigger dataset and the condition is simply a "1" before and after 2010 plus the ID in 2010. I want to keep IDs that are directly captured _on_ 2010 as well. Thanks

Comment: @M.Beausoleil You are very welcome! Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function `subset()`

```
subset(d, y.2010>0 & rowSums(d[,11:14])>0)
```

or if you want that IDs which are captured in 2009:

```
subset(d, (y.2010>0 | y.2009>0) & rowSums(d[,11:14])>0)
```

Also you can use `apply(d[,11:14]>0, 1, any)` in the place of `rowSums(d[,11:14])>0`

Comment: Op wants row 242, so you need `rowSums(d[,3:10])>0` as your first condition

Comment: Your first row does not give the correct output and the second will not work for an `1` in 2008 and another one in 2013.

Comment: @LyzandeR: I dont see in the question any relation to  "`1` in 2008". I think that the questioner can now construct his own solution by the example in the answer.